# Keras loss is not decreasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I tried to learn my NN with [breast Cancer Wisconsin](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data)
 (I add `"id"` column as an index and changed `"diagnosis"` column to 0 and 1 with `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`), but my NN is not reducing Loss.

I tried other optimizers and losses but this isn't working.

That's my NN:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, InputLayer
import tensorflow.nn as tfnn

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(30, activation = tfnn.relu, input_dim = 30))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = 1))

model.add(Dense(60, activation = tfnn.relu))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = 1))

model.add(Dense(1, activation = tfnn.softmax))

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, target, epochs = 6)
```

And my output:

```py
Epoch 1/6
569/569 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/sample - loss: 10.0025 - acc: 0.3726
Epoch 2/6
569/569 [==============================] - 0s 172us/sample - loss: 10.0025 - acc: 0.3726
Epoch 3/6
569/569 [==============================] - 0s 176us/sample - loss: 10.0025 - acc: 0.3726
Epoch 4/6
569/569 [==============================] - 0s 167us/sample - loss: 10.0025 - acc: 0.3726
Epoch 5/6
569/569 [==============================] - 0s 163us/sample - loss: 10.0025 - acc: 0.3726
Epoch 6/6
569/569 [==============================] - 0s 169us/sample - loss: 10.0025 - acc: 0.3726
```

I seems that NN after a few iterations stops learning (look at the time of epochs learning, in the first epoch it's 2s and in others it's 0s and in first epoch speed of processing the data is ms/sample, but in other epochs iits us/sample)
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Softmax has `sum=1`.

You can't use softmax with 1 unit. It will always be 1.

Use `'sigmoid'`.

---

Also be careful with `'relu'`. It may (by luck) fall into an "all-zeros" region and stop evolving.

Ideally, the batch normalization should be before it (this way you guarantee that there will always be some positive numbers):

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(30, input_dim = 30))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = 1))
model.add(Activation(tfnn.relu))

model.add(Dense(60)
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = 1))
model.add(Activation(tfnn.relu))

model.add(Dense(1, activation = tfnn.sigmoid))
```

Comment: You forgot to change the `tfnn.softmax` ;)

Comment: Seems that the order between ReLU & BN is still a topic for debate - see [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/67gonq/d_batch_normalization_before_or_after_relu/) and [fast.ai](https://forums.fast.ai/t/questions-about-batch-normalization/230/4); but both threads are rather old - any more recent reference?

Comment: Hmmm... I think there might be applications where one is better than the other? I don't have the answer, of course, but when I think of the advantages of BN first, I see: "prevent all zeros or too little positive values (which mean frozen or ineffective model)", having actual "zeros" after the relu (that will indeed remove the contribution of certain weights of the next layer, which might work as a sort of dropout).

Comment: On the other hand, using BN after would not create the zeros, but some minimum negative values. Thus, all weights in the next layer will keep their contribution. These minimum values would vary, though, not sure if this might be good or not. There will be no prevention against "all zeros" in the relu.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a binary classification task with a single-unit final layer, you should **not** use `tfnn.softmax` as an activation for this layer. Use `tfnn.sigmoid` instead, i.e.

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation = tfnn.sigmoid))  # last layer
```